# ElementUI table not rendering in a Jest test

Tags: vue-cli, vue-test-utils, element-ui

I have noticed that some of my components that use ElementUI tables are failing their tests, with Jest and Vue-test-utils.
Looking into it some more, when I reproduce a simple example and use `console.log(wrapper.html)` some of the inner parts of the table are simply not being rendered.

I am by no means a frontend expert (more of a Python backend person), and working on this to help another team out and so I am not 100% convinced that I'm not doing something stupid, but I have explored a range of possibilities and I can't figure it out. What's more, the *tests* are not working, but the component itself works absolutely fine within the application - the table is rendered properly. So it's frustrating because it appears to work, but the test suite disagrees....

This is not the actual code, but it's a trimmed down example to reproduce the issue.

`BasicTable.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-table
      :data="tdata"
    >
      <el-table-column #default="{ row }">
        {{ row.item }}
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column #default="{ row }">
        {{ row.size }}
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BasicTable',
  data () {
    return {
      tdata: [{ item: 'A', size: 'L' },
        { item: 'B', size: 'M' },
        { item: 'C', size: 'XS' },
        { item: 'D', size: 'XXL' },
      ],
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

`BasicTable.spec.js`

```
import BasicTable from './BasicTable.vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'


test('Render for basic table', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(ElementUI)

  const wrapper = mount(BasicTable, {
     localVue
  }
  console.log(wrapper.html())
})
```

So I would expect the output of the `wrapper.html()` to just render the table, with the four rows, and two columns, as would be expected from the data.

However, what I actually get is

```
 <div>
      <div class="el-table el-table--fit el-table--enable-row-hover el-table--enable-row-transition">
        <div class="hidden-columns">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="el-table__header-wrapper">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="el-table__header">
            <colgroup></colgroup>
            <thead class="">
              <tr class=""></tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="el-table__body-wrapper is-scrolling-none">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="el-table__body">
            <colgroup></colgroup>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="el-table__row"></tr>
              <tr class="el-table__row"></tr>
              <tr class="el-table__row"></tr>
              <tr class="el-table__row"></tr>
              <!---->
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!---->
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="el-table__column-resize-proxy" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So between the `<tbody></tbody>` tags, the correct number of rows are present (4) but then they seem to have no internal content.

A few things I initially considered but discounted as the issue:

- I made sure I was **mounting** and not **shallowMounting**
- using `LocalVue` and using `ElementUI` does appear to be working, the ElementUI components are being rendered as basic html, with the relevant classes added (e.g. `<table class="el-table">`)
- Some of the actual components use a `computed()` to calculate the data that goes into the table, or have it passed via a prop. I thought this might be causing some issue, but I set up this basic example with the most simple case I could think of (i.e just hardcoded data in the component) and i still see the same result.

I have struggled to find much specific ElementUI/Jest/Vue-test-utils help online, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! And if I have done something stupid, please let me know because as I said this is not my main area of expertise.

Versions of stuff I am using (from `package.json`)

```
 "dependencies": {
    "element-ui": "^2.4.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0"
  },
```

Note: The project is setup with Vue-cli and I believe Jest is bundled with that.

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
```

I run the tests with `npm run test:unit`

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found an answer, so will post it here if anyone else stumbles across this.

The solution appears to be waiting for `nextTick()` for the DOM elements to properly render. I'll be honest, I am not 100% sure why this is the reason - I might expect this if the data was *changing* during the test (and I had used that approach for other tests when updating props or triggering a `click` for example) but in this case the data is passed in while mounting... If you come across this answer and have a more concrete explanation, please feel free to add it here!

So for completeness, something like

```
test('Render for basic table', async () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(ElementUI)

  const wrapper = mount(BasicTable, {
     localVue
  }
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()    <-- added this line (also made the test async)
  console.log(wrapper.html())
})
```

Appears to solve my problem!